# Calling a tampermonkey function from a link

Tags: javascript, function, hyperlink, call, tampermonkey

How can I call a tampermonkey function from a link?

Here's what I tried.  Using tampermonkey, I can insert a link as follows:

```
var aNode = document.createElement('a'); 
var aText = document.createTextNode('will it run');
aNode.appendChild(aText);
aNode.href = 'javascript:runTest();';
document.body.insertBefore(aNode, document.body.firstChild);

function runTest() {
   alert('it ran!');
};
```

When the link is called, the function, runTest(), should be called.  It isn't.  Instead the following error message occurs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: runTest is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set javascript handlers that way.  Use `addEventListener()`, like so:

```
var aNode   = document.createElement ('a');
var aText   = document.createTextNode ('will it run');
aNode.href  = '#';
aNode.appendChild (aText);
document.body.insertBefore (aNode, document.body.firstChild);

aNode.addEventListener ("click", runTest, false);

function runTest (zEvent) {
    zEvent.preventDefault ();
    zEvent.stopPropagation ();

    alert('it ran!');
};
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I was looking for, except cleaner and neater code.